# Control keyboard backlight via command line on IdeaPad 5 slim 16IRL8

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-backlight

I use arch linux and the reason I want this so bad is because my computer doesn't remember the backlight state and turns it on every boot and every time it wakes from deep sleep and I mostly don't need it.

Referring to [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_backlight) I tried both `brightnessctl` and `xset` but none of them seemed to detect it.

my `/sys/class/leds/` looks like

```
input3::capslock
input3::numlock
input3::scrolllock
phy0-led
```

there is neither a `::kbd_backlight` nor a `::thinklight` directory most solutions online are based on them